# How to retrive Edge details in orientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am very new to OrientDB, Here i  wanted to display the information with respect to a particular edge. say for Example consider two nodes/vertex (**person,vehicle**) which are connected by an Edge (**Owns**). Then on click of Edge owns need to display the details of when the person used the car (starting point, destination, date of journey etc.,). Do we have such functionality if so how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see all attributes of Owns:

1) select expand(outE('Owns')) from Person where name="YourName"

or if you want a particular attribute

2) select outE('Owns').starting_point from Person where name="YourName"